# What cause the different times function if the dataframe has a columns name?

Tags: python, pandas

I tested this two snippets,the `df` share the same structure other than the `df.columns`, so what causes the difference between them? And how should I change my second snippet, for example,should I always use the `pandas.DataFrame.mul` or use the other method to avoid this?

```py
# test1
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 10))) \
    .assign(Count=np.random.rand(10))
df.iloc[:, 0:3] *= df['Count']
df
```

```py
Out[1]:
           0          1          2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9     Count
0  26.484949  68.217006   4.902341  61  10  13  31  15  10  11  0.645974
1  56.845743  70.085965  28.106758  79  56  47  82  83  62  40  0.934480
2  33.590667  78.496281   1.634114  94   3  91  16  41  93  55  0.326823
3  51.031974  15.886152  26.145821  67  31  20  81  21  10   8  0.012706
4  47.156128  82.234199  10.458328  24   8  68  44  24   4  50  0.517130
5  18.733256  61.675649  23.531239  74  61  97  20  12   0  95  0.360815
6   4.521820  26.165427  26.145821  68  10  77  67  92  82  11  0.606739
7  24.547026  62.610129  23.531239  50  45  69  94  56  77  56  0.412445
8  52.969897  75.692843   9.804683  73  74   5  10  60  51  77  0.125309
9  21.963128  30.837825  19.609366  75   9  50  68  10  82  96  0.687966
```

```py
#test2
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 10))) \
    .assign(Count=np.random.rand(10))
df.columns = ['find', 'a', 'b', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'Count']
df.iloc[:, 0:3] *= df['Count']
df
```

```py
Out[2]:
 find   a   b   3   4   5   6   7   8   9     Count
0   NaN NaN NaN  63  63  47  81   3  48  34  0.603953
1   NaN NaN NaN  70  48  41  27  78  75  23  0.839635
2   NaN NaN NaN   5  38  52  23   3  75   4  0.515159
3   NaN NaN NaN  40  49  31  25  63  48  25  0.483255
4   NaN NaN NaN  42  89  46  47  78  30   5  0.693555
5   NaN NaN NaN  68  83  81  87   7  54   3  0.108306
6   NaN NaN NaN  74  48  99  67  80  81  36  0.361500
7   NaN NaN NaN  10  19  26  41  11  24  33  0.705899
8   NaN NaN NaN  38  51  83  78   7  31  42  0.838703
9   NaN NaN NaN   2   7  63  14  28  38  10  0.277547
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I see a difference, which I find quite interesting, when I run the two snippets, but I cannot be sure it's the same difference that you are asking about. So yes, this needs details.

Comment: sry I edited the question, it's weird it returns NaN, in test2, but if I use `pandas.DataFrame.mul` this two would be same. I know the values are random, and I sry for type mistake. Hope this time it would be clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.iloc[:,0:3]` is a dataframe with three series, named `find`, `a`, and `b`. `df['Count']` is a series named `Count`. When you multiply these, Pandas tries to match up same-named series, but since there are none, it ends up generating NaN values for all the slots. Then it assigns these NaN:s back to the dataframe.

I *think* that using `.mul` with an appropriate `axis=` is the way around this, but I may be wrong about that...

Comment: Yes, I already tried `.mul ` before, it works. I just want to know the mechanism. And should I try to aviod use `*`? I'm not sure if it's better to always use `.mul`

Comment: I suppose the thing to remember is that binary operators (and, by extension, augmented assignment operators) on dataframes always match columns by name, if there are names. If you like that, binary operators are fine. If you don't, they aren't.